# How to set Allow Parent Paths in IIS Express Config using asp directive

Tags: asp-classic, iis-express

This is a continuation of a answered question in the following link:
[How to set Allow Parent Paths in IIS Express Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769751/how-to-set-allow-parent-paths-in-iis-express-config)

I am running a classic asp web site in IISexpress. 
The same web site is also used in IIS 7.5 in a w7 pro and works fine enabling the parent paths in the IIS configuration of the web but trying to use the web.config in IISExpress does not work

The problem that I am experiencing is that in the suggested web.config in order to enable the parent paths:

```
    <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
      <asp 
         enableParentPaths="true" 
         bufferingOn="true" 
         errorsToNTLog="true" 
         appAllowDebugging="true" 
         appAllowClientDebug="true" 
         scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true">

         <session allowSessionState="true" />
         <cache diskTemplateCacheDirectory="%TEMP%\iisexpress\ASP Compiled Templates" />
         <limits />
      </asp>
     </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

I get a 500 error every time that I try to use any asp tag
If I remove the asp tag it all works fine,
Anybody has a clue?
TIA

Comment: Classic ASP does not use the web.config file

Comment: @Dee IIS does, why do you think there is a `asp` section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not read carefully. The configuration file that mentioned isn't `web.config`. It is `applicationHost.config`. As a shotcut:
Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> 
type

> notepad "%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config"

hit <kbd>⏎</kbd>. 
This will open the host configuration file with notepad. You need to find your web site's section. It's something like `<location path="YourSiteName"> ...  </location>`. Look inside that node, find the `<asp>` section and change with yours. Finally, don't forget to remove the asp section from `web.config`.

Comment: I am looking for location path="site name" but I just have one location path and between double quotes are empty <location path="">. And there is no <asp> tag between location tag. But a bit above of the configuration code there is a <system.webServer><serverRuntime /><asp . I have added that enableParentPaths line between that <asp> tag but didn't change anything, I still get the same error. Can you please help me about it, my question is under that link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108076/iis-express-enabling-parent-paths thanks